# Confusion about the imaginary portion in the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Since intuitively speaking, a Fourier transform decomposes a signal into its frequencies or, in other words, into sinusoids, I'm confused about the exact definition which seems to decompose a signal into real and imaginary sinusoids.

For a real signal, how can it be decomposed into imaginary sinusoids? Are the imaginary portion supposed to all cancel out eventually?

Comment: This is extremely common: even $\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}e^{ix}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-ix}$ and $\sin{x} = \frac{1}{2i}e^{ix}+ \frac{-1}{2i}e^{-ix}$ are made from complex functions that cancel to give a real one.

Comment: The Fourier transform of a real signal is *Hermitian*. It is a linear relation between pairs of it's Fourier coefficients.

Comment: "Are the imaginary portion supposed to all cancel out eventually?" I don't have time to write a proper answer, but: **Yes.**

Comment: @MiloBrandt thanks, just looking for a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real signals:

a. the even part of the real signal gets transformed to the real part of the real signal's Fourier Transform, which will be even; and

b. the odd part of the real signal gets transformed to the imaginary part of the real signal's Fourier Transform, which will be odd.

If $f(t)$ is your real signal, then it's even and odd parts before being transformed, are:

$$f_e(t) = \dfrac{f(t) + f(-t)}{2}$$
$$f_o(t) = \dfrac{f(t) - f(-t)}{2}$$

So, if $f(t)$ is real and

$$F(s) = \mathscr{F}\left\{f(t)\right\}$$

then

$$\Re[F(s)] = \mathscr{F}\left\{f_e(t)\right\}$$
$$i\Im[F(s)] = \mathscr{F}\left\{f_o(t)\right\}$$

Comment: The fourier transform of the odd function is imaginary or real?

Comment: Imaginary.  Take, for example, the fourier transform of $\sin(t)$.  However, when you extract the imaginary part with the $\Im[]$ operator, it returns the imaginary part as a real answer without the $i$.

Comment: I don't understand. How does sin have imaginary frequencies to it?

Comment: It doesn't.  It is purely odd in the time domain, so in the transform domain, it is purely imaginary.  The phase of a frequency component in the fourier transform domain is the degree of oddness or evenness of that frequency component in the time domain - an expression of the phase shift of the cosinusoid in the time domain at $t=0$.  Phase shifts of $0$, $i$, $-1$, and $-i$ in the frequency domain, correspond to cosines with phase shifts of $0$, $-\pi/2$, $-\pi$, and $-3\pi/2$ at $t=0$ in the time domain. BTW, recall that $\sin(t) = \cos(t-\pi/2)$.

Comment: Ah yes this is making sense now. So the imaginary portion only contributes to the phase delay, right?

Comment: Right.  The phase of a particular frequency component in the transform domain corresponds to the phase shift (aka delay) of the cosinusoid of that particular frequency in the time domain.